# GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "usr/local/go"

Tags: go, amazon-ec2

Background:

AWS AMI2 Linux EC2 instance.

Go version go1.13.4 linux/amd64.

Installed using `sudo yum install golang`

---

I have the GOPATH set up to `/home/ec2-user/projects` (I set it up by typing `export GOPATH=/home/ec2-user/projects`

When I try running the build (`go build main.go`) I get the following error:

```
GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "usr/local/go"
```

Which it does not seem to make sense as the GOPATH is `GOPATH="/home/ec2-user/projects"`

Here is what I have when I type `go env`

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/ec2-user/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/ec2-user/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ec2-user/projects"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="direct"
GOROOT="/usr/lib/golang"
GOSUMDB="off"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build909532445=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: What are you trying to build, and how?

Comment: I'm trying to build the main file 'go build main.go'  I edited the question. Thank you for noticing.

Comment: it seems like an issue with GOROOT, can you set export GOROOT="<path to golang bin directory>" and check